# Best way to handle delayed submits on a multi input form?

Tags: javascript, forms

Basically, I have a form like this

[image: I have a form like this]

I want to submit each value from the inputs, but there must be a 5 second delay between when each input is processed. These are some of things I was thinking.

- Each input has it's own form and `action` and submit. And I do an AJAX beside each one.
- Maybe I can do a setTimeout function or something for the number of things recieved in the JavaScript
- I am on Rails backend, so maybe when the `controller#action` recieve the JSON, I can do an interval, where it loops and handles the JSON and
  does stuff every 5 seconds...

There are a variety of things I can try, but I know that there are a lot of great developers that came across these issues and I want to know the best practice to go about this.

Comment: Consider debouncing or throttling your submissions. For example, start by reviewing the appropriate lodash or underscore library docs to see if that behavior meets your needs. As you do so, consider why you need to do this. If you're relying on your client-side code to allow server processing to work on a schedule, it sounds like you may want your server process to be more resilient. What if a buggy script, malicious actor, or another browser session sends requests more frequently than you're expecting?

Comment: I have heard of those libraries, in fact, I used it with React to debounce queries in the `Search for user` input. Up until this point there has been very little consideration to harmful requests. So it will likely be better to debounce/throttle the submissions on the client, since they the server will be unaware of it, until it is received.

Comment: @Palpatim, actually, I am not sure if this is possible. Now that I am implementing it, I don't know if I have the right approach to debouncing. It won't work on the client side, because if we are debouncing, we won't be able to submit all the values to the server. Then we would have to make 5 different requests, I feel.